# stop android default camera

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I have to block android default camera to take picture on particular place(on particular latitude and longitude ).Has anyone do it eariler,help me. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: you do realize that it won't work reliably... locations can be spoofed, GPS could be lost/disabled, people could use alternative camera apps, or they could just do anything by rooting the phone. Ah let's not forget, they could just not-/un-install your app :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

if you instantiate the camera then no other applications can use it until you release it, so just instantiate the cam when in the "red-zone" and release it again when in the "green-zone".

Comment: thanks for reply............can  be stop images clicked by default camera on particular place(on particular latitude and longitude) from saving on gallery or sd card